# how to make ascii file for accounting software with vbscript and ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ascii

i need to have an ascii file that have several lines in it for accounting.

in everyline i will have the text and numbers for example numbers and spaces with specific length for every column of data
first column is 3 char length
second is 5
third is 10 and etc...

then i need the end of the line to end with CR + LF

how do i do an ascii file from classic asp and vbscript?

Comment: Are you needing to create the file on the server or send this content to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [FSO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (FileSystemObject) to work with files in VBScript. This MSDN Page, [Working with Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), shows you how to create and write to files.

Here's a [page](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_createtextfile_filesystem.asp) that has a sample that uses VBScript in an ASP page to create a text file.

Comment: this is what i end up doing and just find out you wrote the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My guess, you need to manage a text file like a database. If I'm right, you can do it using [Text File Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714091%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
You need a [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file for the data construct configuration and an existing text file (*myfile.csv*).

**schema.ini**

```csh
[myfile.csv]
Format=FixedLength
CharacterSet=ANSI
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=first Text Width 3
Col2=second Text Width 5
Col3=third Text Width 10

;[myotherfile.csv]
;Format=FixedLength
;CharacterSet=ANSI
; etc.
```

**myfile.csv** (maybe not certain but there are three columns per line with the above configuration.)

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
123123451234567890
```

Things to do side of ASP are like classical database operations also.

```vb
Const adLockReadOnly = 1
Dim adoCon, adoRS
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="& Server.Mappath(".") & _ 
            ";Extended Properties=""text"""
    Set adoRS = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset")
    With adoRS
        .Open "Select * From [myfile.csv]", adoCon, , adLockReadOnly
        While Not .Eof
            Response.Write( _
            .Fields("first").Value & " - "& _
            .Fields("second").Value & " - "& _ 
            .Fields("third").Value & _ 
            "<br />")
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        .Close
    End With
    Set adoRS = Nothing
    'Data insert : new line ends with CR + LF automatically.
    adoCon.Execute "Insert Into [myfile.csv] Values('aaa','bbbbb','cccccccccc')"    
adoCon.Close
Set adoCon = Nothing
```